# Check the convergence of the sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$U_{n+1}=\frac{k}{1+U_n}, \quad k, U_1 \in \mathbb{R}^+$$

How to prove that this sequence is convergent?

Thank You

Comment: If a sequence converges than it converges to it's fixed point, when you find the fixed point try bounding the function with the fixed point(s) depending on the choice of $U_1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use induction with recurrence relations to show that the distance between the terms of the sequence are getting smaller as $n$ gets large, such that the sequence is converging to some limit $L$.

If the limit $L$ of the sequence exists, then $U_{n} \approx U_{n+1}$ as $n \to \infty$ and $$L=\frac{\sqrt{1+4k}-1}{2}\,.$$

Comment: please give me the complete proof @Infinite Monkey